Unable to display errors on AJAX form until next page load
I just started working with Drupal 10 and I'm having an issue with displaying form validation errors with an AJAX form submit. Everything works fine except the display of form validation errors if the user leaves a required field empty. Anything I have tried to this point displays the error but not until the next page load. At the moment I have an empty module, a form class, and a route for the form. I know I could use a little javascript to handle this but I was hoping to avoid that. Here's my code at the moment:
<?php

namespace Drupal\isbn_converter\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;

class IsbnConverterForm extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'isbn_converter_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $search_isbn = $form_state->get('search_isbn') ?: '';
    $form['search_isbn'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('ISBN 10 or 13'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];

    $form['converted_isbn'] = [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<div id="converted-isbn"></div>',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="converted-isbn-wrapper"><p>Converted ISBN</p>',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Convert'),
      '#button_type' => 'primary',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'convertIsbn'],
      ],
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  if (empty($form_state->getValue('search_isbn'))) {
    $form_state->setErrorByName('search_isbn', $this->t('Please enter a valid ISBN-10 or ISBN-13 number.'));
    $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
  }
}

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

}

  public function convertIsbn(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $isbn = $form_state->getValue('search_isbn');

  if(!empty($isbn)){
    $url = 'https://example.com';
    $xml_request = <<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<request>
    <isbn>$isbn</isbn>
</request>
EOT;

    try {
      $http_client = \Drupal::httpClient();
      $http_response = $http_client->request('POST', $url, [
        'body' => $xml_request,
        'headers' => [
          'Content-Type' => 'application/xml',
        ],
      ]);

      $response = new AjaxResponse();
      $xml_response = $http_response->getBody()->getContents();
      $xml_element = simplexml_load_string($xml_response);

      $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#converted-isbn', (string) $xml_element->results->converted_isbn));
      return $response;

    } catch (ClientException $e) {
      \Drupal::logger('isbn_converter')->error($e->getMessage());
    }
  }

  return null;
}

}

As I said, everything works as I expect so far as the form and ajax call work and the response gets displayed in the browser but I can't seem to make any errors display without a page load.
Any help is appreciated.
